# JavaScript is there anyway to control onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m new to JavaScript

I got a button that that has javascript code and I want it to run some of it at the onclick and when I hit the enter key it will run rest of it. Here is my code.

```
 if($(this).data('clicked'))  
   return false;
 $(this).data('clicked',true);
 $.getJSON('/go.php?live_sess_get=1',function(sdat){
   //pause here until user presses enter key
 }); 
 return false;
```

Comment: This code is not enough to understand.

Comment: Please provide full source code

Answer (score 1):

```
//here is js
function myfunc()
{
//execute innitial code
if (confirm('Are you sure you want proceed?')) {
// Do it!
 } else {
// Do nothing!
 }
}


//here is html button code 
<button type="button" onclick="myfunc()">Click Me!</button>
```